# Changing default location of Quartz job creation

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I have the following directory structure in eclipse (groovy project)

> grails-app/jobs/File1/ABC/D
>   grails-app/jobs/File2/DEF/G

I am using the following command to generate Quartz Job :

```
grails create-job Name_Of_Job
```

By default it is creating the new job inside

> grails-app/jobs/File2/DEF/G/Name_Of_Job

but i want it to be created inside D folder at

> gails-app/jobs/File1/ABC/D.

How do i change the location where the Quartz job is created, i tried using

```
grails create-job c://projectname//Folder//grails-app//jobs//File1//ABC//D//Name_Of_Job
```

but this does not work it treats file location as name of job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should enter a package name in the grails command (similar to e.g. create-domain-class)

This should work:

```
grails create-job File1.ABC.D.Name_Of_Job
```